# Opera sometimes ignoring jquery function until after user interaction with page

Tags: jquery, css, opera

I've come across a very weird bug in opera. Check the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $imgHeight = $('.collection-item-image').width() / 3 * 4;
    $('.collection-item-holder').css('padding-top',$imgHeight + 'px');

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var $imgHeight = $('.collection-item-image').width() / 3 * 4;
        $('.collection-item-holder').css('padding-top',$imgHeight + 'px');
    });
});
```

Sometimes opera will ignore the code to run on document ready. Every other browser runs it fine as it should. I thought maybe it was ignoring the document ready altogether, but I tested it with an alert function and found that it worked everytime. It seems that although it sometimes ignores it under normal document ready conditions, if I add an alert before the functions are run, upon pressing "ok" in the alert box the code is run fine every time. For some reason there are times when a user must interact with the page for it to run.

Anyone know why or even better a way to fix or go around this issue? Bear in mind this only seems to be happening when setting the CSS this way, and on window resize the code executes perfectly and displays as it should.

Comment: *Every other browser runs it fine as it should.* I'm trying to understand your question. What is the expected result? Is `$imgHeight` being calculated incorrectly in Opera?

Comment: It is either ignoring the height, trying to run the function too quickly or calculating the wrong height. Whichever one, the $imgHeight is either incorrect or for some reason not being set correctly if at all.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is causing this issue, but wrapping the function inside `window.load()` has sorted the issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):
"The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code. When using scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties, it's important to reference external stylesheets or embed style elements before referencing the scripts."

In other words, this is run right after the *structure* of the page is ready, NOT when the entire page (images, external links) are loaded. Since you say it *sometimes* works, so this is probably a race condition, when the image loads very fast or is loaded from cache, it *may* be ready when the DOM-ready event fires. In your case, the onload is the appropriate event, when **all** media on the page has loaded.